# Designing custom color picker filter using clarity design

Tags: datagrid, vmware-clarity

The clarity documentation demonstrates the color picker filter in custom filters under datagrid section. Can I get the code for implementation of that filter?

The string filters are easily implementable but writing color picker filter seems to have too  much code on css side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter is in our GitHub project and you can see it here.

https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/website/src/app/documentation/demos/datagrid/utils/color-filter.ts

Comment: Hi Jeremy can you please update this link since this link is not working anymore.